# bower concat CSS problems

Tags: gruntjs

Grunt novice here....what I am trying to do seems so simple, but I am at my wits end here.  I am trying to concat the JS from a few separate bower components and then do the same with the CSS.  Here is the relevant code from my grunt.file:

```
bower_concat: {
      all: {
        dest: 'builds/development/js/_bower.js',
        cssDest: 'builds/development/css/_bower.css'
    }
}
```

This is the last item in my config so does not need a comma after the final "}".

All the needed files are listed under "main" in their respective bower.json files.  For example:

```
"main": [
    "dist/owl.carousel.js",
    "dist/assets/owl.carousel.css",
    "dist/assets/owl.theme.css",
    "dist/assets/owl.transitions.css"
  ],
```

I am positive these paths and file names are correct. The JS concats fine.  The CSS does nothing.  If I remove the "dest:..." line from my gruntfile (in an attempt to concat ONLY the CSS) terminal gives me the error ":Warning: You should specify "dest" and/or "cssDest" properties in your Gruntfile".

I clearly am specifying this. Help!

Answer (score 1):

Finally got it to work with this:

```
bower_concat: {
        all: {
            dest: {
                js: 'builds/development/js/_bower.js',
                css: 'builds/development/css/_bower.css'
            },

        },
    }
```

Essentially needed one more set of nested curly braces inside of "dest:".  For the record you DO NOT need to specify mainFiles if they are designated in the bower_components json.

Comment: Ah! I should have seen this so easily! bower_concat -> name of task -> dest specified. Gaaah! Glad you figured it out though

Answer (score 0):

Ah, easy. You need to specify the component or library and then its mainFiles in your Gruntfile under grunt-bower-concat. Don't worry about messing with the individual components' files.

```
bower_concat: {
    all: {
        dest: 'builds/development/js/_bower.js',
        cssDest: 'builds/development/css/_bower.css'
    }
    mainFiles: [
        owlcarousel: [
            "dist/owl.carousel.js",
            "dist/assets/owl.carousel.css",
            "dist/assets/owl.theme.css",
            "dist/assets/owl.transitions.css"
        ],
    ],
}
```

FYI My current bower-concat for owlcarousel looks like this so double-check your bower_components folder tree structure.

```
bower_concat: {
    all: {
        dest: 'builds/development/js/_bower.js',
        cssDest: 'builds/development/css/_bower.css'
    }
    mainFiles: [
        owlcarousel: [
            "owl-carousel/owl.carousel.js",
            "owl-carousel/owl.carousel.css",
            "owl-carousel/owl.theme.css",
            "owl-carousel/owl.transitions.css"
        ],    // (Version 1.3.2)
    ],
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'm trying to get this to work, but in the meantime can't help but notice that the bower-concat instructions specifically mention that mainFile only needs to be specified for bower components WITHOUT bower.json files...all of which my bower components have.

Comment: If the bower_component that you're installing lacks a main entry in its bower.json, you should override with bower-concat's mainFiles. Editing the bower.json of a package will work, but if it updates and changes, you may have to edit it again and again. -- oh you had a syntax error. No biggie then. Last time I used owlcarousel it lacked a main entry.